# Can't write to status register of SST25VF010A flash memory

Tags: stm32, spi, memory

I'm having trouble writing to the status register of a SST25VF010A-33-4I-SAE 1Mbit SPI flash memory on a board I recently made. I'm using an STM32F401CBU6 to communicate with the memory.

I can read the device ID (0x49) and manufacturer ID (0xBF) without issues however when I read the status register after attempting to write to it nothing in the register changes. Here's the code I'm running.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've got it sending the register value to my laptop over USB and this is what I get in RealTerm.

[image]

I get 0x0C twice meaning the register did not change as 0x0C is the default power-up value. I'm confident my status_reg_read function works as it's returning a reasonable value so maybe my write function? I've got WP# pulled up to 3V3 so write protection shouldn't be an issue since Table 3 in the data sheet states that if WP# is high then status register writing is allowed. So if anyone has some ideas that would be great thanks in advance.

Comment: `nothing in the register changes` ... what were you expecting to see?

Comment: I'm expecting to get read 0x00 as that's what I'm writing to it. This changes the BP0 and BP1 both to zero to disable protection of the entire memory array.

Comment: How fast is the MCU? There must be at least 100ns of CS high between enable and write commands, so does your code violate that? Also have you double checked there is correct amount of bytes being transmitted on bus, only one? You don't show the SPI init code, but the HAL can certainly work with these transactions just fine.

Comment: The MCU is running at 16MHz. I also tried adding a delay of 1ms between the switch of the CS pin but still no luck. Yep I checked on the oscilloscope that the correct amount and values are being sent by the MCU

Answer (score 1):

Very weird "fix" to this. By first writing to the register then reading instead of reading then writing then reading again I get the correct 0x00. Not totally sure why this is but I'll leave this here incase anyone has similar issue in future.

**DOES NOT WORK (returns the default 0x0C):**

[image]

**WORKS (returns the correct 0x00, register has been changed):**

[image]